# Linker errors while compiling a project in netbeans 7.1.1

Tags: c++, gcc, openssl, linker-errors, netbeans-7.1

I am getting a lots of linker errors while i compile a project ,:

I have added all the neccesary files in the linker options and have specifically added the libregistration.dll in the linker options

```
build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/1996578364/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.o: In function `fsend':
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:587: undefined reference to `BIO_write'
build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/1996578364/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.o: In function `frecv':
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:918: undefined reference to `BIO_read'
build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/1996578364/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.o: In function `soap_rand':
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:2969: undefined reference to `RAND_pseudo_bytes'
build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/1996578364/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.o: In function `soap_ssl_init':
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3087: undefined reference to `OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf'
C:\repos\impression\trunk\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3091: undefined reference to `RAND_load_file'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3093: undefined reference to    `RAND_seed'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3096: undefined reference to  `RAND_seed'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3094: undefined reference to `RAND_status'
build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/1996578364/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.o: In function `soap_ssl_error':
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3131: undefined reference to `ERR_peek_error'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3130: undefined reference to `ERR_error_string'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3135: undefined reference to `ERR_error_string_n'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3134: undefined reference to `ERR_get_error'
build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/1996578364/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.o: In function `ssl_auth_init':
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3167: undefined reference to `ERR_clear_error'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3177: undefined reference to  `RAND_load_file'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3217: undefined reference to `RSA_generate_key'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3220: undefined reference to `RSA_free'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3223: undefined reference to `RSA_free'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3231: undefined reference to `DH_generate_parameters'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3234: undefined reference to `BIO_new_file'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3237: undefined reference to `PEM_read_bio_DHparams'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3238: undefined reference to `BI O_free'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3240: undefined reference to `DH_check'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3242: undefined reference to `DH_free'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3245: undefined reference to `DH_free'
build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/1996578364/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.o: In function   `ssl_verify_callback_allow_expired_certificate':
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3374: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_CTX_get_error'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3379: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_CTX_set_error'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/repos/impression/trunk/Registration'
 build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/1996578364/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.o: In function `soap_ssl_accept':
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/repos/impression/trunk/Registration'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3451: undefined reference to `BIO_new_socket'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3489: undefined reference to `X509_verify_cert_error_string'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:3496: undefined reference to `X509_free'
build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/_ext/1996578364/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.o: In function `tcp_connect':
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4115: undefined reference to `BIO_new_socket'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4163: undefined reference to  `X509_verify_cert_error_string'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4178: undefined reference to   `X509_get_ext_count'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4182: undefined reference to `X509_get_ext'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4183: undefined reference to `X509_EXTENSION_get_object'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4183: undefined reference to `OBJ_obj2nid'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4183: undefined reference to `OBJ_nid2sn'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4185: undefined reference to `X509V3_EXT_get'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4199: undefined reference to `ASN1_item_d2i'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4216: undefined reference to `sk_value'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4215: undefined reference to `sk_num'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4222: undefined reference to `X509V3_conf_free'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4222: undefined reference to `sk_pop_free'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4226: undefined reference to `ASN1_item_free'
C:\Registration/../include/gsoap/stdsoap2_ssl_cpp.cpp:4238: undefined reference to `X509_get_subject_name'
 ..................
 collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
 make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/libRegistration.dll] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
 make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2


 BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 8m 28s)
```

Thanks,

Comment: How about link openssl to project?

Comment: i have link openssl to project as well